# How do protons fuse in the sun?

Tags: nuclear-physics, sun, fusion, protons, quantum-tunneling

I know that Nucelar fusion in the sun requires quantum tunneling to occur, as otherwise the Sun's core wouldn't be hot enough to overcome the Fusion barrier.
However while the 2nd and further stage of the Proton-Proton chain I have no problem with, I've noticed an issue with the first stage.
The first stage if the Proton-Proton fusion chain involves 1. Two protons fusing to a diproton. 2. One of the protons changing into a neutron and emitting a Positron.
The issue is that the first step is endothermic.
A diproton has a mass more then a Mev greater then the combinded mass of two protons.

[image]

[image]

How does quantume tuneling occur when the kinetic energy of the two paritcles is not only smaller then the Cloumb barrier, but also smaller then the difference in mass energy between the Diproton and the two protons?

Comment: I think this is to do with the width of the diproton resonance, but others may know more fully.

Comment: Could also be that the protons are moving towards each other and the energy conservation accounts for not only the reference rest masses of the protons but their kinetic energy as well.

Comment: 1.25 Mev?, that's 625Kev each, which corresponds to a temperature of 7E9 Kelvin, At the temperature of the Sun's core each particle has on average 1.5Kev. Though that's only the average and some particles will have more they won't be hot enough.

Comment: Fusion occurs at a very slow rate in the Sun. A cubic meter of the Sun's core produces about the same power as a cubic meter of compost heap. So you expect fusion to be a rare event.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell–Boltzmann_distribution The probablilty of a particle greater then KbT drops faster then exponentially as T increases.

Comment: Probably also relevant? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/374305/25301

Comment: I could be wrong, but if the two individual protons have less energy equivalent than the diproton and are reacting to the diproton, then they must be getting the energy from this should be endothermic reaction (a reaction in which more energy is absorbed than is released). How do you then come to the conclusion that it is an exothermal reaction (a reaction in which more energy is released than is absorbed)?

Comment: Oops, typo fixed